# Cyberduck: Remove ftp:// from connection string

Tags: ftp, file-transfer

I have a client who is allowing me access to a subdomain hosted on his server. I have tested to connection through Mac terminal and I'm able to sign in successfully. However, when attempting to use Cyberduck, I'm having issues.

We've narrowed down the problem to "ftp://" in the connection string. i.e., connecting to subdomain.myserver.com works but ftp://subdomain.myserver.com does not. I looked through the preferences and I don't see a way to remove this. Is there any other way to use Cyberduck to connect via FTP without "ftp://" being used in the connection string?